# Dynamically generated display object as a gradient mask

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gradient, mask

I just want to create a gradient mask –which is generated dynamically through AS3 code– for an object (a pentagon in my following example,) and I simply, cannot! <sup>*[[The SWF file of what I've tried.]](http://www.fastswf.com/9GiBlC4)*</sup>

The code works just fine unless it *ignores* the alpha gradient of the dynamically created `Sprite` for being used as a gradient mask (it's being treated as a solid mask), while the exact code acknowledges the "on-stage" created object (through the user interface) for being a gradient mask!

I think the runtime just cannot cache the object as bitmap and hence the ignorance! However, I'm stuck at making that happen! So please, shed some lights on this, any help is greatly appreciated in advance :)

```
var X:Number = 100, Y:Number = 35, W:Number = 350, H:Number = 150;

var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();
mat.createGradientBox(W, H, 0, X, Y);

var gradientMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
gradientMask.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 255], mat);
gradientMask.graphics.drawRect(X, Y, W, H);
gradientMask.graphics.endFill();

pentagon1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
pentagon2.cacheAsBitmap = true;
onStageGradient.cacheAsBitmap = true;
gradientMask.cacheAsBitmap = true;

pentagon1.mask = gradientMask;
pentagon2.mask = onStageGradient;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _onEnterFrame);
function _onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    pentagon1.x += 7;
    pentagon2.x += 7;

    if (pentagon1.x > 500) {
        pentagon1.x = 0;
        pentagon2.x = 0;
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `gradientMask` to the [display list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dff.html) to have it in effect.

```
pentagon1.parent.addChild(gradientMask);
```

Comment: You're right and you're my hero! thank you :) It would be excellent if you provide a why !)

Comment: A why: Flash engine only cares for the object that are on display list when it does all draws. It's pretty common knowledge.